# How do I access Site Analytics (New privilege)

Tags: discussion, status-completed, site-analytics

So this morning I got a notification which says

> You've earned the "access to site analytics" privilege! Learn more
>   about it in the help center.

Cool, so where is an action button to access that page? I had to click on the notification and than I clicked a link on that page which says

*you can visit **/site-analytics** to explore site statistics in two tabs*

But I don't see a link anywhere on my profile page/account to access the site analytics or am missing something obvious?

Comment: Currently, it seems that the link on the privilege description page is the only link to the site analytics page.

Comment: @SonerGönül I think I've already mentioned that in my question :)

Comment: It should probably be added to [the moderator tools page](http://stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=stats&daterange=today).

Comment: @Dukeling: That's a logical spot. Ideally, the link would be hidden for users with between 10k and 25k, however. We are open to other suggestions as well.

Comment: @JonEricson we can either have them under tools section or we can put it  somewhere on profile/account page..

Comment: Eurgh. As soon as I reach 20k, there is a new carrot to chase!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to the link in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/site-analytics), Oded added a link to the [10k-mod tools page](https://stackoverflow.com/tools) *if* the user looking at the page has the privilege:

[image: 25k user links]

Now, that page could probably use a redesign and the link isn't exactly the most visible thing. But at least there's a link on the site for people to stumble across.

Answer (score 7):

Looks like a new 25k privilege tier. Cool!

https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/site-analytics

> People who run websites use data about how the site is used to make informed decisions. Since our sites are community run, we give the most engaged users special access to some of the data we collect. Once you earn the privilege, you can visit [/site-analytics](https://stackoverflow.com/site-analytics) to explore site statistics in two tabs: